# iOS PageViewController Issue

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a page view controller to display a tutorial screen in my app.The thing i need is that in the last page of the tutorial if i swipe left tutorial view should quit and app should navigate to my home screen. The tutorial view has 5 views and swiping through these views works perfectly , the thing on which am stuck is to get swipe left in the last screen of tutorial. Any idea?

Comment: So I'm clear: the first four left swipes work, but the last left swipe does not work? How does it not work? You should also add your code that shows how you handle the gestures.

Comment: Actually page view controller provides swipe action to navigate through tutorial views.I have added swipe gesture to last page of tutorial but it doesnt work :(

Comment: Take a look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27452673/3985749), which might help, particularly the comments on the answer.  The particular way to return to your home screen may be different, but the way to trigger it should be the same.